# Why does every build change the exe-file?

Tags: delphi, linker, binary-reproducibility

Building the same project (without any changes) produces **binary different** exe-files: some small regions of them are different. Empty project, version information (and auto-increment on every build) is turned off.

Why it happens? And is it possible to make delphi produce binary equal files for the same projects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The various structures in the PE executable file format used by Windows include timestamps that are set by the compiler and linker.

It is possible to post-process the file to reset these values to a defined constant (I wrote a tool to do exactly this for a secure product that needed exact hash values), but this should only be done on ready-to-ship executables, as some debuggers rely on the timestamps for source lookup, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the problem into "How do I avoid compiling if there are no changes to the source", might be easier to deal with.

Comment: What if we have no executable module at all but we want get it equal to existing (somewhere) which corresponds particular revision of projects.

Comment: Or include a request on Quality Central asking for a compiler feature that enables to produce **exactly** equal executables.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect compiler insert to *.exe encoded time, special ordinal numbers (for versioning) and maybe other things :) 
It's impossible to force Delphi to produce equal binary output.

Answer (score 0):

it may be, that some actual time-stamps are compiled into the exe-file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: November 27th 2008. Sorry thence I was not so familiar with SO, and now I do not go thru my olde posts and actualise them. But I am still sure, that my answer answers part of the Asker's question, why twice compiling produces different binaries. f.e. I generate a version.h file with #define VERSION and timestamp as first compile step and use that define in debug output.